# Avoid read by other session issue in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

According to this blog [post](https://logicalread.com/oracle-read-by-other-session-wait-event/#.WNEdH2996M8),

```
If two or more sessions request the same information, 
the first session will read the data into the buffer cache while other sessions wait
```

Actually, we are getting too many `read by other session` event in `Oracle`. This is happing due to single `SQL` e.g,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA JOIN TABLEB JOIN TABLEC
```

Is there way to tell oracle, if 2 or more simultaneous users request the same information then get the information concurrently instead of waiting.
 In SQL Server we can use `nolock`. Is there is something in Oracle.

Comment: `nolock` is not going to help you here, even if you were on SQL Server. That blog post you mentioned has some hints and tips on what you can do to improve things. However, by the sounds of it, you're possibly reading data into the buffer cache and then throwing it away relatively quickly. Have you considered increasing the SGA and buffer cache sizes on your database? That could help you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "get the information concurrently". Could you please edit your question and explain more clearly what you're trying to do?

Comment: BobJarvis, Actually lot of users are in waiting state, I don't want any wait. Boneist, I am just have an SP that executed multiple times, how can I `throwing it away relatively quickly`?

Comment: @user960567 When Oracle determines that it needs to fetch a block of data (e.g. because it's been asked to select some data from a table), it will check the buffer cache to see if it's in there. If it's not, it goes to the physical disk and fetches it from there and (usually) stores it in the buffer cache. That means that the next time that data needs to be accessed, it can be read straight from the cache (which is a lot quicker than going to disk). However, if the buffer cache is full, data that has been least recently used (LRU) will be removed to make room for the new data.

Comment: @user960567 so, in your case, I'm wondering if the data is being cycled too quickly - i.e. loaded into the buffer cache but then pushed out again as more data is loaded due to there not being enough space. The `read by other session` wait simply means that session has determined that another session is already doing the work to fetch the data from the physical disk - there is no point in forcing the second session to redo this work, so it waits. Once the data is in the cache, sessions will be able to read it concurrently.

Comment: @Boneist is raising great points.  It isn't clear whether full scans are involved here, but full scans typically add to the least-recent LRU where they can age out quickly.  If these tables are being full-scanned frequently and aging out, have you considered CACHEing these tables?  Have you considered multiple buffer pools?

Comment: I don't think we have space issue because our servers have more than 256 GB of RAM

Comment: Yes, but how much of that is allocated to your database's SGA (and within the SGA to your buffer cache)?

Comment: @Boneist Will check and let you know?

Comment: Back to the original question, no, you cannot set some parameter to get two or more sessions to read from disk at the same time.  This is discussed in the blog post you mentioned.  The fixes for this is going to be related to possibly SGA adjustments, as mentioned already, or changes in the data model to eliminate hot blocks or changes in the queries to reduce the number of gets/reads, or, sometimes both.  Is there any additional information you cab provide on your data model, queries, or explain plans that would help apply some knowledge to your problem?